In IEEE LaTeX format, how to avoid parameters getting capitalized in Subsection Titles?
In a paper I am writing to IEEE journal, I need to mention the parameters like $a$, $b$, $c$ in section titles, but when I run LaTeX (in IEEE style file), they are coming out capitalized. I wish to avoid them looking like $A$, $B$, $C$  as output.
Can you solve this problem?!
I used
\subsection{Parameter $a$ varying}


I cannot see and [tag:latex3] relation. And what is “the IEEE style file”? There are several classes and packages related to IEEE. Can you please explain your issue in detail, i.e. add a minimal working example?

Indeed it would be necessary to know which style file you use. I tried to reproduce with the MWE \documentclass{IEEEtran} \begin{document} \section{Parameter $a$ varying} \end{document} but this works fine (the a is lower case), so either it is not IEEEtran or it is but you use additional packages or settings that modify the appearance of section titles.

Sorry, I used in \subsection !

Also with \subsection it looks fine in my MWE in my comment above. Please add a similar complete document to your question that shows the issue.

\documentclass{ieeeaccess}... For this journal, all section titles and subsection titles are capitalized.. it is the journal format. However, the parameters I am using are in small size, this is the problem for me.

Please see the second link in my first comment, so we would not need to guess any longer and also not need to search essential information in comments.

Why make people guess what document class you are using, and change the question in comments????  Make a complete document that shows the problem (like the one in the posted answer)

unlike IEEEtran, there is no ieeeaccess class in texlive, so if you are using such a class where is it from?

@David I can reproduce with `\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Parameter $a$ varying}
\subsection{Parameter $b$ varying}
\EOD
\end{document}` and the class from https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/downloadTemplate?publicationTypeId=1&titleId=201&articleId=1&fileId=541.

@Marijn see my answer:-)


IEEEtran uses \MakeUpperCase and unless you hve an old version of latex, that automatically skips over inline math.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Parameter $a$ varying}
xxx
\clearpage
bbb

\end{document}

Note the a is lowercase in the uppercase heading.

IEEEACCESS

The ieeeaccess class from
https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/guide-for-authors/preparing-your-article/
is completely broken, it requires (but doesn't load) graphicx and it uses \uppercase directly which doesn't skip math and would break any UTF-8 non ASCII characters.
This is a quick fix

\documentclass[journal]{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}% needed grrr

\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{1pt}{-1pc plus -1pt minus -1pt}%
              {0.001pt}{\raggedright\color{accessblue}\sectionAfont\MakeUppercase}}%
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{1pt}{-1pc plus -1pt minus -1pt}%
              {1pt}{\raggedright\color{greycolor}\sectionBfont\MakeUppercase}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Parameter $a$ varying}
\subsection{Parameter $a$ varying in subsection}
xx
\clearpage
bbb

\EOD
\end{document}



You should report this to IEEE

Friends, I solved the problem with the help of the package
\usepackage{soul}

in the preamble.
For the subsection title, I used..
\subsection{Varying the parameter \lowercase{a}}

This works very well and the parameter 'a' comes in bold font as well.
I am sharing this solution as kind info. Thank you!

But now your a is no longer math.

I tested with $a$ and the letter 'a'. The output is better without math and it comes good in bold font. So I retaining the command as \lowercase{a} and not \lowercase{$a$}. Both work, I tested.. Thanks!

this is really bad advice, the a is no longer math and \lowercase like the \uppercase used by the class should never be used in latex, it will break any non ascii text.

also what has the soul package got to do with this? it is completely unrelated to the rest of your answer.
